# Retry attempts with Spring Cloud Hysterix

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix, circuit-breaker

Cn anyone please guide me as to how to give retry attempts in Spring Cloud Eureka Hysterix command as below ? Also by default does Spring Cloud breaks the circuit on the first failure to the called method ?

Please advice.

```
@HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod="getDataFallBack" )
    public ResponseEntity<CurrencyConversion> addConversionFactor(@RequestBody CurrencyConversion currencyConversion) throws Exception{
        log.info("in addConversionFactor ... " + currencyConversion);
        //some operations here
        return ResponseEntity.ok(currencyConversion);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hystrix acts as a circuit breaker and does not provide any retry functionality. It's up to the calling client to implement retries. With Spring Cloud, you could either use Spring Cloud Netflix `@LoadBalanced` `RestTemplate` (or `WebClient`) or directly use [Spring Retry](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/retry.html).

There are a couple of different configuration properties on `@HystrixCommand` that control when a circuit breaker trips. A full overview of all available properties is available here: https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/Configuration. The one that controls error thresholds is [circuitBreaker.errorThresholdPercentage](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/Configuration#circuitbreakererrorthresholdpercentage).

Please also note that Spring Cloud Hystrix is deprecated. If you are creating a new application, you should consider using [Spring Cloud Circuit Breaker](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-circuitbreaker) instead.